# Watchpoints: don't break if triggered from specific method

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a watchpoint in IntelliJ IDEA to break when a member variable is changed ("member").

That works quite well. But is there a way to NOT break on specific method calls?

For example: I have a class "ClassA" that contains function "a", "b" and "c" which are all modifying the member variable "member".
I have multiple classes accessing these methods. One of the classes is triggering method "a" hundreds of times ("ClassB").

Can i stop IntelliJ IDEA from breaking if the modifing of the variable "member" originates from "ClassB"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the breakpoint configuration dialog there's a `More` option in the bottom left hand corner, this will load a detailed configuration dialog which allows you to set a `Class Filter`. See the following screenshots:

[image: Initial Breakpoint Dialog]
[image: Detailed Breakpoint Dialog]
[image: Define Class Filter]

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!